# Rails 6 webpacker $(...).modal is not a function - importing dynamic packs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have a Rails 6 app in which I am trying to use webpacker. I *was* using it succcessfully and importing all packs in my `application.js` file but instead now I just want to import the application.js file that has jquery and bootstrap in it, and dynamically load the correct pack based on the controller.

For instance, my previous configuration was

```
import "bootstrap"
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("../packs/classrooms")
require("../packs/lunch_choices")
require("../packs/events")
require("../packs/users")
```

What I'd rather do is remove all packs from the `application.js` file and just import the correct pack dynamically like so...

> Application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag "#{controller_name}", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

If I view the source code when I reload the page and restart the server, I see that the pack does load, however, I get the following error.

> $(...).modal is not a function

Since the application file is being loaded first and that's the one that contains jquery, why am I getting this error? This was working when I was including all packs in application.js, but now that I want to split by the pack it does not.

Here is my `environments.js` file - this has never changed since setting up my app.

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', 
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
module.exports = environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Each pack is a separate dependency graph. Without extra configuration, the graphs are not shared. I would guess you’re either accessing a function on the wrong dependency graph or possibly clobbering one instance of jQuery for another in the global scope.

Splitting your code into multiple packs, while possible, is error-prone and works against the way webpack was intended to be used.

Try consolidating everything into just one pack and splitting code with dynamic imports instead. Your “page-specific” code would live in another folder, like `app/javascript/pages`, and might be imported conditionally, based on the presence of a certain DOM element, for example. This achieves the goal of producing smaller bundles from one pack while keeping all your code in the same dependency graph.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/